# Go named arguments

Tags: python-3.x, reflection, go

How can I pass dictionary as list of arguments for function like in Python 3 in Go?

Python 3:

```
def bar(a,b,c):
    print(a,b,c)

args={c: 1, b: 2, a: 3}
bar(**args)
```

Go blank:

```
func bar( a, b, c int) {
    fmt.Printf("%d, %d, %d", a, b, c)
}

func main(){
    args := make(map[string]int)
    args["a"] = 3
    args["b"] = 2
    args["c"] = 1
    // what next ?
}
```

Comment: Can it be implemented by Golang reflection?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible. You'd need to use a struct to do anything even remotely close to this (and it is a remote likeness)

```
type Args struct {
    A, B, C int
}

func bar(args *Args) {
    fmt.Printf("%d, %d, %d", args.A, args.B, args.C)
}

func main() {
    args := new(Args)
    args.A = 3
    args.B = 2
    args.C = 1
    bar(args)
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call it that way, using `bar(&Args{B:2})` works.

Comment: Yes, of course, I called it that way to maintain visual similarity with the example given, for whatever that's worth.

Comment: Also of note since this answer has gotten a few up votes, the question immediately prompted me to think of the net/rpc package which has to deal with variable args and so the answer is taken in whole from that. Looking at how the standard lib does things is often some of the best advice one can take in regards to Go, see: http://golang.org/pkg/net/rpc/

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the other answers, which I see no need to repeat, be aware that Go will auto-unpack function calls with multiple return arguments provided:

1. Every return value is a parameter of the function
2. Every parameter is a return value of the function

(That is, the types of the function's argument list is identical to the other function's return list).

```
func Args() (a int, b int, c int) {
    return 1,2,3
}

func Bar(a,b,c int) {
    fmt.Println(a,b,c)
}

func main() {
    Bar(Args())
}
```

Will print `1,2,3`. Obviously this example is a tad silly, but I find this covers most cases of tuple and dict unpacking as arguments in Python, which tend to be a quick and dirty way of passing one function's return values as another function's arguments.

Comment: awesome, this is one of those cases I was thinking I just wasn't aware of, I didn't realize you could pass those unpacked values directly to another func.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness sake you can either use what dskinner said, or if you want a "dictionary" (called map in Go) you could use one easily, for [`example`](http://play.golang.org/p/57X6_ItBgA) :

```
package main

import "log"

type ArgsMap map[string]interface{}

func bar(am ArgsMap) {
    if v, ok := am["foo"].(string); ok {
        log.Println("bar", v)
    } else {
        log.Println("bar no foo")
    }
}

// Or

type Args struct {
    foo     string
    boo     int
    a, b, c float32
}

func bar2(a Args) {
    if a.foo != "" {
        log.Println("bar2", a.foo)
    } else {
        log.Println("bar2 no foo")
    }
}

func main() {
    bar(ArgsMap{"foo": "map", "blah": 10})
    bar(ArgsMap{})

    bar2(Args{foo: "struct"})
    bar2(Args{})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct equivalent to Python's `*args/**kwargs` syntax. You need to use one of the solutions outlined in the other answers.

In case you just need to pass an unknown number of arguments you can make your function [variadic](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func bar(numbers ...int) {
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", numbers)
}

func main() {
    bar(3, 2, 1)       // prints [3 2 1]
    bar(5, 4, 3, 2, 1) // prints [5 4 3 2 1]
}
```

[Play](http://play.golang.org/p/JbMDtPUSHI)

Answer (score 1):

This is not thoroughly tested for a wide range of values, but it works for a few simple cases. Feel free to expand it further for your own needs. It's also not guaranteed to be anything like the best way to do this, and error checking is left as an exercise for the reader.

```
func parseArguments(args ...interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    if args == nil {
        return nil
    }
    if x,ok := args[0].(map[string]interface{}); ok {
        return x
    }
    x := map[string]interface{}{}
    for i := 0; i < len(args); i += 2 {
        x[ args[i].(string) ] = args[i+1]
    }
    return x
}

func DoSomethingCool(x ...interface{}) {
    args := parseArguments(x);
    // args is now a map of type map[string]interface{}
}
```

You can now call `DoSomethingCool()` in any of the following ways:

```
// No arguments
DoSomethingCool()

// These two are equivalent, and result in
// args = map[string]interface{}{
//     "foo": "bar",
//     "baz": "qux",
//  } 
DoSomethingCool(map[string]string{"foo": "bar", "baz": "qux"})
DoSomethingCool("foo","bar","baz","qux")

// Or you can even mix types for the keys, thanks to interface{}
// These two are also equivalents and result in
// args = map[string]interface{}{
//     "foo": 20,
//     "bar": false,
//  } 

DoSomethingCool(map[string]interface{}{"foo": 20, "bar": false})
DoSomethingCool("foo",20,"bar",false)
```

If you don't have a need to mix value types, you could just as well use `map[string]string` I imagine.

Comment: Did you not mean mix value types on that last one?

Comment: @Aicos: Yes, thank you for noticing the error. I have corrected the answer.